# Date validation not working consistantly in c++

Tags: c++, date, validation

Heyyy, I made this program to add user defined number of days to a given date. In here I added code for date validation to make sure that user enters the correct date in the first place, my problem is the validation is not working consistently, some times it gets stuck in an infinite loop while taking the day of the month again, and we can't predict when, it's not consistent, for e.g. in a run it got stuck in that loop when you entered the incorrect month, but in the next run it might not get stuck in that loop when you again enter the incorrect month. What's wrong with my program ? I've also tried several compilers, the problem persist.

P.S. The program works as intended if user enters the correct date in first place.

Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

class calendar
{
public:
    int d,m,y;
    calendar(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        d=day;
        m=month;
        y=year;
    }
    void Add()
    {
        int ms[13]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}, a;
        cout<<"\n\nEnter number of days you wanna add to the given date: ";
        cin>>a;
        d=d+a;
        if(y%4==0)
        {
            ms[2]=29;
        }
        while(d>ms[m])
        {
            d=d-ms[m];
            m++;
            if(m>12)
            {
                m=m-12;
                y++;
                if(y%4==0)
                {
                    ms[2]=29;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void display1()
    {
        cout<<"\nEntered Date is: "<<d<<"/"<<m<<"/"<<y;
    }
    void display2()
    {
        cout<<"\nUpdated Date is: "<<d<<"/"<<m<<"/"<<y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int d,m,y,a,b,c;
    cout<<"Enter the day of the month: ";
    cin>>d;
    cout<<"\nEnter the month: ";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"\nEnter the year: ";
    cin>>y;
    while(1)
    {
        if(y<1)
        {
            cout<<"\n\nEntered year is invalid !\n";
            cout<<"\nEnter the year again: ";
            cin>>c;
            y=c;
        }
        else if((y%4==0 && m==2 && d>29) || (y%4!=0 && m==2 && d>28) || (d>30 && m==4 || m==6 || m==9 || m==11) || (d>31 && m==1 || m==3 || m==5 || m==7 || m==8 || m==10 || m==12) || (d<1))
        {
            cout<<"\n\nEntered day of month is invalid !\n";
            cout<<"\nEnter the day of the month again: ";
            cin>>b;
            d=b;
        }
        else if(m>12 || m<1)
        {
            cout<<"\n\nEntered month is invalid !\n";
            cout<<"\nEnter the month again: ";
            cin>>a;
            m=a;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    calendar e(d,m,y);
    e.display1();
    e.Add();
    e.display2();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Image:
[Output with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpsjM.jpg)

Output with error:

```
Enter the day of the month: 56 
Enter the month: 3 
Enter the year: 3 
Entered day of month is invalid ! 
Enter the day of the month again: 3 
Entered day of month is invalid ! 
Enter the day of the month again: 3 
Entered day of month is invalid ! 
Enter the day of the month again:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the feedback from the community, this is the final program that seems to be working perfectly in my testing. Thank you soo much you all :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

class calendar
{
public:
    int d,m,y;
    calendar(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        d=day;
        m=month;
        y=year;
    }
    void Add()
    {
        int ms[13]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}, a;
        cout<<"\n\nEnter number of days you wanna add to the given date: ";
        cin>>a;
        d=d+a;
        if(y%400 == 0 || (y%4 == 0 && y%100 != 0))
        {
            ms[2]=29;
        }
        while(d>ms[m])
        {
            d=d-ms[m];
            m++;
            if(m>12)
            {
                m=m-12;
                y++;
                if(y%400 == 0 || (y%4 == 0 && y%100 != 0))
                {
                    ms[2]=29;
                }
                else
                {
                    ms[2]=28;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void display1()
    {
        cout<<"\nEntered Date is: "<<d<<"/"<<m<<"/"<<y;
    }
    void display2()
    {
        cout<<"\nUpdated Date is: "<<d<<"/"<<m<<"/"<<y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int d,m,y,a,b,c;
    cout<<"Enter the day of the month: ";
    cin>>d;
    cout<<"\nEnter the month: ";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"\nEnter the year: ";
    cin>>y;
    while(1)
    {
        if(y<1)
        {
            cout<<"\n\nEntered year is invalid !\n";
            cout<<"\nEnter the year again: ";
            cin>>c;
            y=c;
        }
        else if(((y%400 == 0 || (y%4 == 0 && y%100 != 0)) && m==2 && d>29) || (((y%400 == 0 || (y%4 == 0 && y%100 != 0))!=true) && m==2 && d>28) || (d>30 && (m==4 || m==6 || m==9 || m==11)) || (d>31 && (m==1 || m==3 || m==5 || m==7 || m==8 || m==10 || m==12)) || (d<1))
        {
            cout<<"\n\nEntered day of month is invalid !\n";
            cout<<"\nEnter the day of the month again: ";
            cin>>b;
            d=b;
        }
        else if(m>12 || m<1)
        {
            cout<<"\n\nEntered month is invalid !\n";
            cout<<"\nEnter the month again: ";
            cin>>a;
            m=a;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    calendar e(d,m,y);
    e.display1();
    e.Add();
    e.display2();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```